# Need really simple help creating AlarmManager (Beginner)

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, background-service

I need a really simple explanation for the following:

I need a background service for my app, that runs even if the app isn't open.
The examples I searched online don't work for me or my cases, so I really need detailled help here.

On the push of a button I want to start a task, that shows me instantly and all 5 minutes that it runs (I don't know what practice would be good to check this).

I know I need to work with an AlarmManager for this, but they never work.
Can you make it really simple for a beginner? Thank you!

EDIT1:

```
public void scheduleAlarm(View V)
{
    Long time = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+5*1000;
    Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Scheduled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Triggered!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

I used the example in the link below and got this now. The alarm should fire the Toast every 5 seconds, right? But it doesn't do it.
I see "Alarm Scheduled" but nothing happens afterwards...

Comment: *"...but they never work"*.  Why not?  What have you tried?  Post your code.

Comment: I deleted it, because it causes the app to crash, even without warnings or errors in the logs, super weird. I just need this as simple as it gets as example and then I can try it out if it really works, and what was different than before

Comment: Concurrency isn't simple, regardless of how you look at it.  SO doesn't provide free code, it helps with code that you have.  Try again, find the problem, then post.

Comment: I put my code now, which I got with the help of the link below, maybe you can help with that now?

Comment: I feel like you are trying to solve an XY problem here.  If you need a background service, why are you not just using a background service?  Why have you chosen AlarmManager?

Comment: Read the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/training/scheduling/alarms.html). With downloadable example.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps start off by reading through [the Java tutorial on concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/), and then move on to [this Android tutorial](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/05/android-alarm-manager_31.html) specifically talking about `AlarmManager`s.

With the vagueness of your question I'm not sure what other help I can give you.

Comment: Thank you, I read your example there and the alarm gets scheduled, but never triggers now : /